how to mint nfts with metadata in reactjs javascript
This my package.json file:
{
  "name": "sol-final",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@metaplex-foundation/js": "^0.20.1",
    "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata": "^3.2.1",
    "@metaplex-foundation/umi": "^0.9.2",
    "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults": "^0.9.2",
    "@metaplex/js": "^4.12.0",
    "@project-serum/anchor": "^0.26.0",
    "@solana-mobile/wallet-adapter-mobile": "^2.1.3",
    "@solana/spl-token": "^0.4.6",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-base": "^0.9.4",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-react": "^0.15.21",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui": "^0.9.5",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-walletconnect": "^0.1.16",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets": "^0.16.0",
    "@solana/web3.js": "^1.36.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@walletconnect/web3-provider": "^1.8.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "bs58": "^6.0.0",
    "buffer": "6.0.3",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "tweetnacl": "^1.0.3",
    "tweetnacl-util": "^0.15.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set HTTPS=true && set SSL_CRT_FILE=localhost.pem && set SSL_KEY_FILE=localhost-key.pem&&react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false && react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ajv": "^7.2.4",
    "assert": "^2.1.0",
    "browser": "^0.2.6",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "url": "^0.11.3",
    "webpack": "^5.91.0"
  }
}

This my code:
import * as anchor from '@project-serum/anchor';

/* Core Solana NPM funtions */
import {
    Connection,
    LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
    Transaction,
    clusterApiUrl,
    PublicKey,
    Keypair,
} from "@solana/web3.js";

/* Core Solana SPL token function NPM */
import {
    createTransferInstruction,
    getAssociatedTokenAddress,
    createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction,
    ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    createApproveInstruction,
    createMint,
    mintTo,
    approveChecked,
    getAccount,
    getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount,
    getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint,
    MINT_SIZE,
    createInitializeMint2Instruction,
    MintLayout
} from "@solana/spl-token";

/* Solana Wallet Adapters */
import {
    PhantomWalletAdapter,
    SolflareWalletAdapter,
    MathWalletAdapter,
} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets';

/* Solana Mobile wallet adapter */
import {
    SolanaMobileWalletAdapter,
    createDefaultAuthorizationResultCache,
    createDefaultAddressSelector,
    createDefaultWalletNotFoundHandler,
} from "@solana-mobile/wallet-adapter-mobile";

/* Solana Math Wallet connect Adapter */
import { WalletConnectWalletAdapter } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-walletconnect';
// import { Metaplex, keypairIdentity, bundlrStorage } from '@metaplex-foundation/js';

/* IDL of Program */
import idl from '../idl.json'

/* Neccassary NPM */
import axios from 'axios';
import { Metadata, MetadataDataData, createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction,createAndMint,mplTokenMetadata,TokenStandard } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata';
import { createUmi } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults';
import { createSignerFromKeypair, generateSigner, percentAmount, signerIdentity } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi';
const { SystemProgram } = anchor.web3;

const MintNFT = async () => {
    // Connect to cluster
    const umi = createUmi('https://soft-late-tent.solana-devnet.quiknode.pro/07a90297e0945453e902ac44beae4efbffb4bafb/');

    const userWallet = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(new Uint8Array("3XMuQJU9TDfdTwowz5msBn1wowowM4y7XvJ5odZSwEwowowqJ12KsG6SYC3LSbDj4NEZqZVcdNFvGCwowV6HKpBojkWw0wpb7"));
    const userWalletSigner = createSignerFromKeypair(umi, userWallet);
    
    const mint = generateSigner(umi);
    umi.use(signerIdentity(userWalletSigner));
    umi.use(mplTokenMetadata());
    
    createAndMint(umi, {
      mint,
      authority: umi.identity,
      name: 'VanthuruDaPulla',
      uri: 'https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmSD4dtfZCyaxZW1eiX7jyfUrUJ43jj8bS559FCVij7ePq/tokenname46_soulbound_camino_5.txt',
      sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(500),
      tokenOwner: userWallet.publicKey,
      tokenStandard: TokenStandard.NonFungible,
    })
      .sendAndConfirm(umi)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Successfully minted NFT:', mint.publicKey);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error('Error minting NFT:', err);
      });
};

If import @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata this NPM I am getting this error:
Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at ./node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/dist/src/errors.js (http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:3214:40)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:149296:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:148690:32)
    at fn (http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:148954:21)
    at ./node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/dist/src/hooked/metadataDelegateRoleSeed.js (http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:22043:18)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:149296:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:148690:32)
    at fn (http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:148954:21)
    at ./node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/dist/src/hooked/index.js (http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:22023:14)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:149296:31)


You might want to check how you are initializing the keypair
import { base58 } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi/serializers";

const uintKey = base58.serialize(
    "3XMuQJU9TDfdTwowz5msBn1wowowM4y7XvJ5odZSwEwowowqJ12KsG6SYC3LSbDj4NEZqZVcdNFvGCwowV6HKpBojkWw0wpb7"
); // Replace with your secret key

const kp = Keypair.fromSecretKey(uintKey);
console.log(kp.publicKey);

This is invalid syntax that Typescript should flag new Uint8Array("3XMuQJU9TDfdTwowz5msBn1wowowM4y7XvJ5odZSwEwowowqJ12KsG6SYC3LSbDj4NEZqZVcdNFvGCwowV6HKpBojkWw0wpb7")

Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null at ./node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/dist/src/errors.js
when i import this npm @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata i am facing this error

is the library installed?
